How to set window title of Electron.NET app
I have the following Electron.NET app:
using ElectronNET.API;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);
builder.Services.AddElectron();
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ElectronWebsiteWrapper_");

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
await app.StartAsync();

BrowserWindow browserWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(app.Configuration["Url"]);
browserWindow.SetMenuBarVisibility(false);
browserWindow.SetTitle("Hello world");
browserWindow.Maximize();

app.WaitForShutdown();

When setting app.Configuration["Url"] (e.g. via environment variable ElectronWebsiteWrapper_Url to https://www.google.com), the application window title is set to the website's title:

However, it should be Hello world as I explicitly call browserWindow.SetTitle.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Thx!

Not sure if this is how its supposed to be done but I do this:
var window = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(new BrowserWindowOptions() { Title = "test123" });
window.OnPageTitleUpdated += (title) => window.SetTitle("test123");

